# Antonym of 'Formalize'

Tags: antonyms

Is there an antonym for 'Formalize'?

As to make something not formal.
Would it be Deformalize, Unformalise, Informalize, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Deformalize* is the correct term. The [dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/deformalize) gives the origin and definition :

> to make less formal; Origin: 
>   1875–80; de- + formalize

However, the dictionary doesn't give records of [*unformalise*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unformalised) or [*informalize*](http://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&search=informalised)

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had looked  on that site already and could not find the term, guess not.

Answer (score 1):

*Deformalize* and *informalize* both are synonyms and mean exactly what you are looking for - the antonym for *formalize*. Since *informal* is a well-known word (an antonym for *formal*), it should be easier for others to understand *informalize* than to understand *deformalize*.

Also note that as *formal* means *being in accord with established forms, following a certain order*, an antonym to this could also be *disorder*, which expresses an *absence of order; state of not being arranged in an orderly manner.*